# Set background picture on webpage when using a masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages

Is there away to set a background image on a webpage when the webpage is based on a masterpage. Notice its not the background of the masterpage i want to change, but the background of the page which use the masterpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a style rule for body{} or whatever on the actual ASPX page. It will override any style set at the master page level.

edit: example:

```
<%@ Page Title="Example" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TroubleShootScanning.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="SpectrumTechnologies.TroubleShootingScanning" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
    <style type='text/css'>
        body { background-image: url(images/bgimage.jpg); }
    </style>
    <!-- the rest of the page here -->
</asp:Content>
```

This will override any values set in a stylesheet.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to use a style rule

Answer (score 2):

You could put a content placeholder on the master page that is within the header.

Then in your content page, put a content control where you could include the second modified CSS stylesheet or STYLE block directly.

Comment: I should state that I can't stand CSS randomly scattered throughout the document or attached directly to elements.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding an `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ExtraStyles" runat="server" />` tag to the header of the Masterpage. That way you can add the following to your page:

```
<asp:Content ID="ExtraStylesContent" ContentPLaceHolderId="ExtraStyles" runat="server">
  <style type="text/css">
  body {background-image:url('someotherimage.jpg');
  </style>
</asp:Content>
```

By adding an extra ContentPlaceHolder you won't get the scattered style tags, they will end up in the head tag of the rendered html.

Comment: This is the way I always do it, use it for adding page specific JS files as well, and mettags also (i.e. I am on a product page and I want to alter the default meta tag keywords / description)

Answer (score 1):

There's an additional trick to add to this...(Second line below)
Also helps the background show while testing locally.